# Error using osmnx：Failed to create field name 'osmid'

Tags: python, python-3.x, osmnx, fiona

When running the following code in Python 3.11:

> ```
> import fiona 
> import geopandas as gpd 
> import pandas as pd 
> import networkx as nx 
> import osmnx as ox 
> G = ox.graph_from_point((37.79, -122.41), dist=1000, network_type='all') 
> ox.save_graph_shapefile(G, "2.shp","C:\\MY")
> ```

The following error occurred when running the above code:

> ```
> CPLE_AppDefinedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
> File fiona\ogrext.pyx:1221, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start()
>
> File fiona\_err.pyx:267, in fiona._err.exc_wrap_int()
>
> CPLE_AppDefinedError: Failed to create field name 'osmid': cannot convert to C:\MY
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> SchemaError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[2], line 3
>       1 G = ox.graph_from_point((37.79, -122.41), dist=1000, network_type='all')
>       2 # G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
> ----> 3 ox.save_graph_shapefile(G, "2.shp","C:\\MY")
>
> File C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\io.py:113, in save_graph_shapefile(G, filepath, encoding, directed)
>     110 gdf_edges = _stringify_nonnumeric_cols(gdf_edges)
>     112 # save the nodes and edges as separate ESRI shapefiles
> --> 113 gdf_nodes.to_file(filepath_nodes, driver="ESRI Shapefile", index=True, encoding=encoding)
>     114 gdf_edges.to_file(filepath_edges, driver="ESRI Shapefile", index=True, encoding=encoding)
>     115 utils.log(f"Saved graph as shapefiles at {filepath!r}")
>
> File C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:1264, in GeoDataFrame.to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
>    1173 """Write the ``GeoDataFrame`` to a file.
>    1174 
>    1175 By default, an ESRI shapefile is written, but any OGR data source
>    (...)
>    1260 
>    1261 """
>    1262 from geopandas.io.file import _to_file
> -> 1264 _to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
>
> File C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:612, in _to_file(df, filename, driver, schema, index, mode, crs, engine, **kwargs)
>     609     raise ValueError(f"'mode' should be one of 'w' or 'a', got '{mode}' instead")
>     611 if engine == "fiona":
> --> 612     _to_file_fiona(df, filename, driver, schema, crs, mode, **kwargs)
>     613 elif engine == "pyogrio":
>     614     _to_file_pyogrio(df, filename, driver, schema, crs, mode, **kwargs)
>
> File C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:638, in _to_file_fiona(df, filename, driver, schema, crs, mode, **kwargs)
>     636 elif crs:
>     637     crs_wkt = crs.to_wkt("WKT1_GDAL")
> --> 638 with fiona.open(
>     639     filename, mode=mode, driver=driver, crs_wkt=crs_wkt, schema=schema, **kwargs
>     640 ) as colxn:
>     641     colxn.writerecords(df.iterfeatures())
>
> File C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py:408, in ensure_env_with_credentials.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>     405 @wraps(f)
>     406 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
>     407     if local._env:
> --> 408         return f(*args, **kwargs)
>     409     else:
>     410         if isinstance(args[0], str):
>
> File C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py:280, in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, **kwargs)
>     278     else:
>     279         this_schema = None
> --> 280     c = Collection(path, mode, crs=crs, driver=driver, schema=this_schema,
>     281                    encoding=encoding, layer=layer, enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers, crs_wkt=crs_wkt,
>     282                    **kwargs)
>     283 else:
>     284     raise ValueError(
>     285         "mode string must be one of 'r', 'w', or 'a', not %s" % mode)
>
> File C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py:165, in Collection.__init__(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, **kwargs)
>     163     elif self.mode in ('a', 'w'):
>     164         self.session = WritingSession()
> --> 165         self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
>     166 except IOError:
>     167     self.session = None
>
> File fiona\ogrext.pyx:1227, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start()
>
> SchemaError: Failed to create field name 'osmid': cannot convert to C:\MY
> ```

I attempted to resolve the issue by reinstalling Osmnx, reinstalling its dependency packages, using virtual environments, etc., but none of them worked and the error persisted.

Comment: What version of OSMnx are you using and how exactly did you install it? Looking at your traceback, it looks like you didn't follow the installation instructions: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: I follow the installation instructions(osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)  to install osmnx1.8.1.   But  I use jupyter notebook to run the code.

Comment: I know what's going on. I should use " ox.save_graph_shapefile(G,"C:\\MY") "  instead of " ox.save_graph_shapefile(G, "1.shp","C:\\MY") ".  Previously, using this code ( ox.save_graph_shapefile(G, "1.shp","C:\\MY"))  was feasible, so I  didn't pay special attention to it.

Comment: Note that the `save_graph_shapefile` function was deprecated long ago and will be removed in a future release, like it says in the user warning when you ran it. Use the `save_graph_geopackage` function instead. Best to avoid shapefiles in general nowadays: http://switchfromshapefile.org/